# c# make multiple different methods trigger a bool

Tags: c#, methods, triggers, boolean

I'm trying to catch and handle content changes of a listview (add, rename, delete items) on my own as there are no predefined events that do the job. I read about the approach to place and switch a bool in all functions that do the changes but that is ugly coding, which I'd like to avoid. That's why I'm asking if anybody knows a way to register multiple methods as triggers for a bool which in turn tells if considerable changes were made, something like this pseudo code:

```
bool changesDetected = false;

void AddItem()
{...}
void RenameItem()
{...}
void RemoveItem()
{...}    

void WatchOutForChanges()
{
   if(AddItemHasCompleted || RenameItemHasCompleted || RemoveItemHasCompleted)
   {
      changesDetected = true;
   }
}

void FormClosing()
{
   if(changesDetected)
   {
      // Save File Choice
   }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a case of using Events?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own delegate, event, and event handler, and invoke method to capture the changes.  However, I think what you are looking for is a way to handle the events that a ListView already has (in Windows Forms):

```
    bool changesDetected = false;

    public void Setup()
    {
        ListView view = new ListView();
        view.AfterLabelEdit += WatchOutForChanges;
        view.ControlAdded += WatchOutForChanges;
        view.ControlRemoved += WatchOutForChanges;
    }

    public void WatchOutForChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changesDetected = true;
    }
```

Comment: The idea as such looks great, but the problem is, the default events won't work for me, so I use my own functions as a workaround. How would I subscribe a custom function the way you illustrated above?